# Is Espresso replaceText() faster than typeText()?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am seeing that Espresso test execution time is much less when I use replaceText() is some places. replaceText() definitely seems faster than typeText().
My assumption is that it paste over existing text(if any present) instead of typing single char at a time.
Is my assumption accurate?

Comment: That has been my observation too.

Comment: `typeText` attempts to focus and enters text letter by letter on a keyboard, `replaceText` calls `TextView.setText` directly. So yes, `replaceText` is faster.